# Installing cordova plugin in cordova 3.4

Tags: git, plugins, cordova, hybrid

I am trying to install a cordova plugin in my mobile app. I am using cordova 3.4. when ever I am executing the line

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/kdileep1990/com.dileep.plugins.datepicker`

in Node.js command prompt, it is throwing me an error

> Error:"git" command line tool is not installd: make sure it is
>   accessible on your path.
>   But I have already installed git.

Could anybody help me regarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While installing git you need to select **Run Git from the Windows Command Promt** option 
If you have not selected this option uninstall and reinstall with this option

[image]